# VSZ and RSS kept increasing on AIX

Tags: c++

I see an abnormal memory usage pattern while running my application program on AIX...

I have created a simple program to malloc and free replicate the same problem.

```
int main()
{
    int *ptr_one;

    // enter value as 0.
    // I wanted few secs fetch the PID of this statndlone process
    // and run 'ps -p <PID> -o "vsz rssize"'
    long a;
    scanf("%ld", &a);

    for(;;)
    {
        if(a < 10000000) a = a + 100;

        ptr_one = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int)*a);

        if (ptr_one == 0){
        printf("ERROR: Out of memory\n");
        return 1;
        }
        *ptr_one = 25;
        printf("%d\n", *ptr_one);

        free(ptr_one);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I have captured the memory usage of this program using the below command,

```
ps -p $1 -o "vsz rssize" | tail -1  >> out.txt
```

The graph tells the memory kept growing and not released.
Is this a sign of leak or this is a normal memory behavior on AIX?

Answer (score 0):

It is fully correct that process'es memory usage size is not decreased: while `malloc` can request additional memory for the process, `free` never return it to the system. Instead, freeing memory is reused in future `malloc` calls.